# npm package published via github not appearing in npm module search

Tags: npm, github-package-registry

I published a package via Github's package manager, and it seemed to work. It appears on the [repo's web page](https://github.com/franklinharvey/time-remaining) and on [my profile page](https://github.com/franklinharvey?tab=packages). When I run

```sh
npm install @franklinharvey/time-remaining@1.0.0
```

locally it works, but when I try it in a new environment such as Replit or CodeSandbox it does not appear. It also does not appear on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/)

Here are some config files

#### .npmrc

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/franklinharvey
```

#### .yarnrc

```
"@franklinharvey:time-remaining" "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
```

#### package.json (partial)

```
"name": "@franklinharvey/time-remaining",
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
},
"repository": {
    "url": "git@github.com:franklinharvey/time-remaining.git"
}
```

#### .npmignore

```
.gitignore
src/
*.log
*.tsbuildinfo

package-lock.json
yarn.lock

coverage
node_modules
```

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Our company also publishes its npm packages via github. Your post gave me an idea, and it fixed the issue on our end.

In a nutshell, I think you need both a fuller `.npmrc` where you're trying to download the package and not succeeding (containing the registry info as below); as well as to do an `npm login` if your package is private.

My `.npmrc`:

```
@my-company-s-npm-account:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=[GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN_HERE_WITHOUT_BRACKETS]
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Hope this fixes your issue.

If you can't add an `.npmrc` or do an `npm login` where you're trying to install it, and your package is private, I'm not sure how to help.